# Nested Gridview and Newly Created Row Dissappears on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 2 Gridvies the first load data of pages and on the edit button a newly added row appears underneath. It then creates a grid in that row the problem is when there is a post back i need to have that row recreated. In my code the newly added GridView editing event handler doesn't fire I need to be able to recreate that row on postback and have the GridView that fire the post back go into edit mode. I don't know what todo at this point can someone help me please, here is my code. by the way PageSettings is a GridView and WebservicesGrid is the nested one

```
protected void PageSettings_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    lblStatus.Text = string.Format("Editing Row: {0}", (e.NewEditIndex + 1).ToString());
}

public int EditIndex = -1;
protected void PageSettings_DataBound
     (object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{

    if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0 && 
        ((GridView)sender).EditIndex == EditIndex 
        || 
        Request["__EVENTTARGET"] == "ctl00$MainContent$PageSettings$ct103$WebServicesGridView" )
    {            
        GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(e.Row.RowIndex+ 2, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);
        row.CssClass = "gridview-alternating-row";
        //row.Cells.AddRange(CreateCells());

        TableCell cell;
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = 2;
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        cell = new TableCell();
        cell.ColumnSpan = 4;

        SystemPage SysPage = e.Row.DataItem as SystemPage;
        GridView gv = CreateGridView("WebServices", SysPage);
        cell.Controls.Add(gv);
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        // Row Edting Event not firing either
        gv.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(services_RowEditing);

        Table table = e.Row.Parent as Table;
        table.Rows.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + 2, row);
    }
}

private GridView CreateGridView(string type, SystemPage page)
{
    GridView services = new GridView();
    switch (type)
    {
        case "WebServices" :

            CommandField CommandEdit = new CommandField();
            CommandEdit.ButtonType = ButtonType.Link;
            CommandEdit.ShowEditButton = true;
            CommandEdit.UpdateText = "Update";
            CommandEdit.EditText = "Edit";                
            services.Columns.Add(CommandEdit);

            BoundField WebServiceName = new BoundField();
            WebServiceName.DataField = "name";
            WebServiceName.HeaderText = "WebService";
            services.Columns.Add(WebServiceName);

            BoundField WebServiceUrl = new BoundField();
            WebServiceUrl.DataField = "url";
            WebServiceUrl.HeaderText = "Url";
            services.Columns.Add(WebServiceUrl);

            List<WebService> list = new List<WebService>();
            list.Add(new WebService { Name = "Test", Url = "Test" });

            services.ID = "WebServicesGridView";
            services.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

            services.DataSource = list;
            services.DataBind();

            break;
    }

    return services;

}

protected void services_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    ((GridView)sender).EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    lblSubGridStatus.Text = e.NewEditIndex.ToString();

    PageSettings.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: You **really** need to re-think your approach here. Creating `GridViews` or other controls programmatically is a very bad idea because of all the problems you've already run into. Can you define your second `GridView` in the markup, and hen show/hide it based on the row state? That would be a good start, I think.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try adding your nested grid-view in [RowCreated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcreated%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) event.
2. First bind the editing event handler to the grid and then add the grid the page. i.e.
3. Try binding nested grid after you have bound the event handler and added the grid to the cell.

EDIT:

Well, #1 might be difficult for you as you are using data-item which will be available only in data-bound event. For #2 and #3,

```
private void CreateGridView(string type, SystemPage page, Cell parent)
{
   GridView services = new GridView();
   ...
   services.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(services_RowEditing);
   parent.Add(services);
   services.DataSource = list;
   services.DataBind();
}

protected void PageSettings_DataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
   ....

   SystemPage SysPage = e.Row.DataItem as SystemPage;
   // add the row first to the page
   row.Cells.Add(cell);
   Table table = e.Row.Parent as Table;
   table.Rows.AddAt(e.Row.RowIndex + 2, row);
   CreateGridView("WebServices", sysPage, cell);
}
```

Comment: I get an error on my table object it says object reference not set to an instance of an object. can you edit my code show me what you mean. I trieded it and im not getting the results

Comment: its got to be the Table table = e.row.Parent as Table not setting table = null

Comment: I'll give that a go but most probably the row will disappear what then

Comment: @KDM, you need to check if data-bound event gets fired on the post-back. If you are relying on view-state to re-create your rows in post-back then the event may not be fired. In such case re-bind the outer grid in the post-ack scenario.

Comment: I did that and the next rows data disappears and the event doesn't fire

Comment: can you update my code to reflect you're comment about viewstate and postback please I don't quite understand all this yet

Comment: I am calling PageSettings.DataBind() on the event so it's not firing at all. Is there another way to make this event fire

Comment: @KDM, PageSettings_DataBound event must be fired on post-back for recreating your nested grid. Can you put a debugger break-point in the event to check if that's happening? And if the PageSettings_DataBound is not getting fired then you have to call re-bind PageSettings grid in say Page_Load event.

Comment: Yeah its not being called on the second click event on the second grid so what what should i add now some code would be nice. I called PageSettings.DataBind() on postback bu. Need to fix that and things will be sweett the services_RowEditing is not being fired, if we can fix that things will be sweet